# How to put several attributes of a record with one Haml line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

In erb we can have

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

to put name and email in one line both on the resulting page and in the code.

What is the best way to do the same with Haml?

```
=@user.name << ', ' << @user.email
```

and

```
="#{@user.name}, #{@user.email}"
```

both work, but lack the Haml beauty. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do straight interpolation:

```
%p #{@user.name}, #{@user.email}
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I don't want a paragraph's style, the shortest way is %div #{@user.name}, #{@user.email}?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what tag it is in. It just will interpolate.

Comment: `%p= [@user.name, @user.email].join(', ')` would work too and scales out nicely.

Comment: I'd argue that you probably need to use helpers if you need to scale that pattern.